# Issue with setting the focus for textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I am working with UWP app using MVVM pattern, below is my code snippet to set the focus, but it not setting the focus to textbox.

**XAML**

```
<TextBox FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="32" Text="{Binding ProSeg1, Mode= TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Center" MaxLength="3" 
                             x:Name="txtSeg" KeyUp="txtSeg_KeyUp"
                             Style="{StaticResource textboxTemplate}" Width="105" />
```

**UserControl.xaml.cs**

```
//this code is executed from constructor.
bool val = txtSeg.Focus( FocusState.Keyboard);
```

Variable `val` is always returned false. In another instance, the same code has used for another `TextBox`, but it is triggered by a `Button` event and it works fine.

Comment: u want to set focus on a textbox right ?

Comment: I can't remember offhand, but I *think* that the control visuals don't exist at the time of the constructor.  You'd have to set focus after the control has actually been drawn, which would be on a Load event.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next time please check out some formatting guides, because your code was not displayed properly (especially the XAML part was not visibile at all), because it didn't have the proper indentation.

Comment: according to MSDN: For a control to receive input focus, it must be enabled, visible, and have IsTabStop and HitTestVisible property values of true. your TextBox wasn't visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `Focus` in constructor is too early, as the control is not yet ready to receive focus and will always return `false`. You must wait until the user control or at least the `TextBox` is fully loaded. In the constructor attach the `Loaded` event:

```
this.Loaded += UserControl_Loaded;
```

And add the following event handler:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtSeg.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

Also note that you should use `FocusState.Programmatic` as the `Keyboard` is reserved for when the control gets focus naturally using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key whereas `Programmatic` is for setting focus in code.

Comment: It works. Thanks for your answer. Do you have a reference for UWP app view lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether or not your XAML has been loaded. If you set the focus in the Window constructor the view won't be loaded so you will have to put your `bool val = txtSeg.Focus( FocusState.Keyboard);` in a Loaded event.

txtSeg won't be focusable until the window is loaded

You could attach to Window loaded or to Textbox Loaded to focus to your textbox